# Convert C++ type int16_t to int64_t without modifying the underlying binary

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to generate a hash code for an object in 3D space so it can be quickly found in an array using a binary search algorithm.

Since each object in this array has a unique XYZ location, I figured I could use those three values to generate the hash code. I used the following code to try and generate the hash code.

```
int64_t generateCode(int16_t x, int16_t y, int16_t z) {
    int64_t hashCode = z;//Set Z bits.
    hashCode <<= 16;//Shift them 16 bits.
    hashCode |= y;//Set Y bits.
    hashCode <<= 16;//Shift them 16 bits.
    hashCode |= x;//Set X bits.
}
```

Now here is the problem from what I can tell. Consider the following peace of code:

```
int16_t x = -1;
cout << "X: " << bitset<16>(x) << endl;//Prints the binary value of X.
int64_t y = x;//Set Y to X. This will automatically cast the types.
cout << "Y: " << bitset<64>(y) << endl;//Prints the binary value of Y.
```

The output of this program is as follows:

```
X: 1111111111111111
Y: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

It keeps the numerical value of the number, but changes the underlying binary to do that. I don't want to modify that binary so I can have an output like the following:

```
X: 1111111111111111
Y: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
```

By doing that, I can then create a unique hash code from the XYZ values that would look like the following:

```
           Unused            X                 Y                 Z
HashCode: [0000000000000000][0000000000000000][0000000000000000][0000000000000000]
```

And that will be used for the binary search.

Comment: If your number is not an actual number, just a series of bytes, use unsigned. Not only do you not need the signedness of your signed number, it actually harms you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `int16_t` to a `uint16_t` first, then merge them together into a `uint64_t` that you finally cast to a `int64_t`:

```
int64_t generateCode(int16_t x, int16_t y, int16_t z) {
    uint64_t hashCode = static_cast<uint16_t>(z);
    hashCode <<= 16;
    hashCode |= static_cast<uint16_t>(y);
    hashCode <<= 16;
    hashCode |= static_cast<uint16_t>(x);
    return static_cast<int64_t>(hashCode);
}
```

The `int16_t`/`int64_t` types will be a two's complement representation (7.20.1.1 paragraph 1 of the C standard requires this), so converting them to a `uint*_t` of the same size will be a bit-wise no-op.

Comment: I maybe nitpicking but I would use `reinterpret_cast` here. It better shows your intentions.

Comment: @NO_NAME: I'm pretty sure that's not legal, and it certainly doesn't compile.

Comment: I was thinking about `reinterpret_cast<uint16_t&>`. EDIT: I tested it. It compiles with g++ 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Most compilers will understand and optimize this to do what you actually want:

```
int16_t a[4] = { 0, z, y, x };
int64_t res;
memcpy(&res, a, sizeof(res));
```

(The compiler will understand that `memcpy` can be done by a simple 64-bit memory operation, and not actually calling the real `memcpy`)

Comment: This is the better solution for what I'm doing here. It's really clever actually, and it's what I used in my code. I still chose Cornstalk's solution as the answer because it better answers the more immediate question.

Comment: I like this approach, but it's worth pointing out that `a` should be set to `{ z, y, x, 0 }` in order to retain the exact bit pattern described in the question (assuming a little-endian system).

Comment: It still produces a unique hash code though, which is what I really needed in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try `int64_t y = (uint16_t) x;`

What this does is, it'll make sure the added extra bits are 0 and not 1, since this is unsigned. Make sure you check the sign bit though.